# Slim Framework show info when using old api version

Tags: slim

I am following [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/) for using Slim Groups to version my API. I just wanted to know if it is possible to capture all calls against an old version without the need to do this for every function. Like a wildcard, you know?

E.g. I updated from v1 to v2 so the call: `myapi.com/v1/user/1` should return: You are using an old API version.

But I don't want to do it like this (for every function):

```
$app->group('/v1', function () use ($app) {
    $app->group('/user', function () use ($app) {
        $app->get('/:id', function ($id) {
            echo "You are using an old version.";
        });
    });
});
```

But more like this (that he ignores all subparts and parameters):

```
$app->get('/v1/*', function ($id) {
   echo "You are using an old version.";
});
```

This is just a private API that only my App that will know how to handle this will use so please don't care about backward compatibility ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return just the message for any `/v1/anything/can/be/here` routes, then you could use wildcard routes ([docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/params/#wildcard-route-parameters)).

```
$app->get('/v1/:anything+', function () use ($app) {
    $app->halt(400, 'You are using old API');
});
```

If you want to keep the old API still working, but want to modify the response to include the message, use group middleware.

```
<?php
$app->group('/v1', function () use $(app) {
    // this is the middleware
    echo 'You are using old API';
    // $app->stop(); // uncomment to stop HERE
}, function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/:id', function ($id) {
        // logic for the route
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh my god this was exactly the wildcard what I was looking for =) Didn't thought the "+" would include all subroutes =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$app->group('/v1', function() {
    $this->any('', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response->withJson(
            array("error"   => TRUE, "msg"  => "You are using old API"),
            400 // status code
        );
    });
});
```